# How to trim milliseconds of a timestamp field in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a table `EMPLOYEE` and it has two `TIMESTAMP` fields `"CRTE_DTM"` and `"END_DTM"`.

I would like to create a view on top `EMPLOYEE` table where I can put some function on these two fields to return `TIMESTAMP` with only 3 precision of milliseconds.

Example:

If I have below row in `EMPLOYEE` table

```
CRTE_DTM
----------------
10-SEP-02 02.10.10.123000000 PM
```

I would like to trim the timestamp to have only 3 precision in milliseconds, see below,

```
CRTE_DTM
----------------
10-SEP-02 02.10.10.123 PM
```

Note: I'm using this view to load data into a table where `"CRTE_DTM"` and `"END_DTM"` fields are TIMESTAMP's

Comment: "TRIM" is a string operation, not a date or timestamp operation. Dates and timestamps, like numbers, can be **truncated** or **rounded**. Which one do you need? Or are all your timestamps having seconds with only three decimal places of precision anyway, despite the timestamp fields having higher *stated* precision? One solution, as already offered by someone else, is to define the new column as data type `timestamp(3)`, and allow Oracle to do the rounding in the process of inserting values from the old table into the new one. This will **round** to nearest millisecond, is that OK?

Comment: The two timestamps you are showing are the same. It's just like the number 12.34 and 12.34000 are the same; trailing zeros behind the decimal point don't change the value. So there is no problem. If you should have data with a timepart like 02:10:10.1234, there still would be no real problem, because you could always display them with only a precision of only three digits. If you really want to prevent the database from storing more than three digits of decimal precision then define your columns as `timestamp(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT <other_columns>
     , CAST(crte_dtm AS TIMESTAMP(3)) AS crte_dtm
     , CAST(end_dtm AS TIMESTAMP(3)) AS end_dtm
  FROM employee;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you can recreate the table (or add columns, copy data, drop the old and rename) you can use the datatype `TIMESTAMP(3)`. The default for `TIMESTAMP` is 6 fractional digits, but it can be overridden.

Alternatively you can convert to a string with a specified format and (optionally if you want to work with TIMESTAMP) back again:

```
select to_timestamp(
    to_char(crte_dtm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'),
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') from employee;
```

Comment: I think this will fail. I get `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` when trying to use `TO_CHAR()` with a format mask containing more than two `F`s (or fewer than two, for that matter).

Comment: Sorry, didn't check that. Try with 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924).

Answer (score 0):

`10-SEP-02 02.10.10.123000000 PM` is the same timestamp as `10-SEP-02 02.10.10.123 PM`. What you can do is select a string showing this timestamp in the desired format:

```
select to_char(timestamp_column, 'dd-MON-yy hh24.mi.ss.ff3', 'nls_date_language=english')
from mytable;
```

Comment: This returns a string but the question is to get a `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit: Yepp. What I am saying is: the timestamp is already there. There is no need to convert, because there are just three digits. So the "issue" may be the default output when querying the data, but this can always be overridden with `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score -2):

```
select localtimestamp(9) from dual;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.